# Proper way to allocate more payload space in Netfilter?

Tags: c, linux, netfilter

I'm writing a netfilter hook in linux. Now, for some outgoing packet, I need to add some payload. In order to be sure that I have enough space in the buffer, I'm checking the available space with

`skb_tailroom(skb)`

Now, if the free space returned is less than the payload lenght I'm adding, I need to add some space. I have not very clear which is the proper way to do it.

I saw some specific functions, like the

`skb_copy_expand`

but this does not look the correct one for the netfilter hook, because it is going to change the original pointer of the buffer. May be "krealloc" on the data pointer?
I tried to search for a reference, in order to understand if there is a "recommended" way to do it, but I didn' found anything.
Could you please give me some guidance on this?

Thanks,